# Show that quadratics $f, g\in\mathbb {C}[x, y]$ have at most four common zeroes, unless they have a non-constant factor in common.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Here is a problem from *Algebra*, Artin:

> Suppose $f, g\in\mathbb {C}[x, y]$ are quadratic. Prove that $f$ and $g$ have at most four common zeroes, unless they have a non-constant factor in common.

1. The book gives the general fact that the number of comnon zeros of such $\mathit f, \mathit g$ (no need to be quadratic) is bounded by the *Bezout bound* and also gives the proof of the finiteness of the number of common zeroes. So with this fact the above problem is obviously solved.
2. I am trying solving the problem without *Bezout's Theorem*. Are there some special properties of quadratic polynomials help to solve the problem?

Comment: Consider the equations in $\Bbb C[x][y]$ and build resolvents.

Answer (score 2):

First, the question is about intersection of two conics in the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2$. Clearly, it reduces to the question about intersection of two conics in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$. So, I will think of $f$ and $g$ as of homogeneous quadratic polynomials in three variables.

If $f$ is irreducible, then the conic $C_f = \{f = 0\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Any isomorphism $\phi \colon \mathbb{P}^1 \to C_f$ is given by quadratic polynomials (it is equivalent to the Veronese embedding). The points of intersection $C_f \cap C_g$ correspond to zeroes of the polynomial $g \circ \phi$, which is a homogeneous polynomial of degree 4 in two variables, hence has 4 zeroes on $\mathbb{P}^1$.

If $f$ is reducible, then $C_f = L_1 \cup L_2$, and you can check that $L_i \cap C_g$ consists of at most 2 points each by the same argument.

So, a short form of this answer is that **rationality** of a conic helps.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Sasha's answer, let me give a somewhat adventitious proof based on elementary geometry.

Just as @Sasha, I reduce the question to proving that two conics in $\mathbb{P}^2$ have at most $4$ points of intersection unless they are degenerate and have a line (or two) in common.

To prove this, I assume the contrary. So there are two conics $C$ and $D$ that have more than $4$ points of intersection and yet no line in common.

Pick two points of intersection of $C$ and $D$, and call them $A$ and $B$.

Now, one quirk of the complex projective plane is that there are two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ at infinity that have the property that they belong to all circles. More precisely,

**(1)** the conics that pass through both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are precisely the circles as well as the degenerate conics containing the line at infinity.

These two points are given in homogeneous Cartesian coordinates by $P_1 = \left(1 : i : 0\right)$ and $P_2 = \left(1 : -i : 0\right)$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Proving **(1)** is fairly straightforward -- just check that a conic given by the equation $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + dyz + ezx + fxy = 0$ contains $P_1$ and $P_2$ if and only if it satisfies $a = b$ and $f = 0$, but the latter two conditions transform the equation of the conic into $\left(ax^2 + ezx\right) + \left(ay^2 + dyz\right) + cz^2 = 0$, which is either a circle or a line united with the line at infinity.

Now, obviously, we can pick any (invertible) projective transformation and apply it to both $C$ and $D$; this does not change the number of points of intersection of $C$ with $D$. In particular, we can pick any projective transformation that sends $A$ and $B$ to $P_1$ and $P_2$. (Such a transformation exists: Indeed, any given three non-collinear points can be mapped to any three given non-collinear points by a projective transformation. To prove this, recall that projective transformations of $\mathbb{P}^2$ are given by invertible $3\times 3$-matrices.) After applying this transformation, the two conics $C$ and $D$ now pass through $P_1$ and $P_2$, and thus are circles or pairs of lines (by **(1)**). If they are both circles, then we are done: Indeed, we know that two circles have at most $2$ finite points of intersection, which (combined with the at most $2$ infinite points they may have in common) yields that they have at most $4$ points of intersection; thus we get a contradiction to our assumption. If one of them is a pair of lines, then our life is even easier (because each of the two lines intersects the other circle or pair of lines in at most $2$ points, and thus again we get at most $4$ points of intersection).

I'm afraid there are no pictures for this kind of argument, though.